# Trying to stream my first app using streamlit Python 3.6.8 on Mac Monterey 12.7.3 Yet I got zsh: permission denied:

Tags: zsh, python-3.6, streamlit

I've been trying to stream my first app using Streamlit. I have installed Streamlit through my terminal and it was successful yet when I try to run the code using Python terminal I receive the following warning

> Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
> command:
>
> Streamlit run Path

and when I try to use my mac terminal I receive

> zsh: permission denied: path

I've tried to change the permission settings for the folder but it didn't work I tried to change the location and I got different error which is

> zsh: no such file or directory: file path

I tried to use the command

```
Streamlit run file path
```

but I received

> zsh: command not found: Streamlit

even tho Streamlit is correctly and successfully installed!

I also tried the command

```
chmod +x HomePage.py
```

> chmod: HomePage.py: No such file or directory

```
python3 HomePage.py
```

received

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'HomePage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I would appreciate any help